# Flutter iOS - Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework Reachability'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

Getting this error when I'm archiving the my flutter iOS code.
Deleted the podfile.lock and re created it and tried flutter clean also.
Cleaned the build folder of XCode still facing the issue.

Here is the error:

**Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework Reachability'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Multiple commands produce '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hinidgvwjhoehcerqbcexmpdpldc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework':

1. Target 'Reachability' has create directory command with output '/Users/tusharsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hinidgvwjhoehcerqbcexmpdpldc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'
2. Target 'ReachabilitySwift' has create directory command with output '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hinidgvwjhoehcerqbcexmpdpldc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework**

Here's the pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Podfile.lock

```
PODS:
  - awesome_notifications (0.0.3):
    - Flutter
  - connectivity_plus (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - ReachabilitySwift
  - device_info (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - device_info_plus (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - Firebase/Analytics (8.14.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Core (8.14.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 8.14.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 8.14.0)
  - Firebase/Crashlytics (8.14.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 8.14.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (8.14.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (~> 8.14.0)
  - firebase_analytics (8.3.4):
    - Firebase/Analytics (= 8.14.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (1.14.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.14.0)
    - Flutter
  - firebase_crashlytics (2.6.1):
    - Firebase/Crashlytics (= 8.14.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_messaging (11.2.12):
    - Firebase/Messaging (= 8.14.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAnalytics (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 8.14.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 8.14.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseCore (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.7)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.14.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - FirebaseInstallations (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.7)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - FirebaseMessaging (8.14.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - flutter_app_badger (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_local_notifications (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_statusbarcolor_ns (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - FMDB (2.7.5):
    - FMDB/standard (= 2.7.5)
  - FMDB/standard (2.7.5)
  - geocoding (1.0.5):
    - Flutter
  - geolocator_apple (1.2.0):
    - Flutter
  - google_maps_flutter (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - GoogleMaps
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (8.14.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (= 8.14.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (8.14.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (= 8.14.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (8.14.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (9.1.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.2)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleMaps (4.2.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 4.2.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (4.2.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (4.2.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.7.0):
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.7.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - keyboard_visibility (0.5.0):
    - Flutter
    - Reachability
  - nanopb (2.30908.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30908.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30908.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30908.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30908.0)
  - package_info (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - path_provider_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - PromisesObjC (2.1.0)
  - Reachability (3.2)
  - ReachabilitySwift (5.0.0)
  - share_plus (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - shared_preferences (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - sqflite (0.0.2):
    - Flutter
    - FMDB (>= 2.7.5)
  - url_launcher_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - webview_flutter_wkwebview (0.0.1):
    - Flutter

DEPENDENCIES:
  - awesome_notifications (from `.symlinks/plugins/awesome_notifications/ios`)
  - connectivity_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`)
  - device_info (from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`)
  - device_info_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/ios`)
  - firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`)
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`)
  - firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)
  - flutter_app_badger (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_app_badger/ios`)
  - flutter_local_notifications (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`)
  - flutter_statusbarcolor_ns (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns/ios`)
  - geocoding (from `.symlinks/plugins/geocoding/ios`)
  - geolocator_apple (from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios`)
  - google_maps_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`)
  - keyboard_visibility (from `.symlinks/plugins/keyboard_visibility/ios`)
  - package_info (from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios`)
  - path_provider_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`)
  - share_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios`)
  - shared_preferences (from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`)
  - sqflite (from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`)
  - url_launcher_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`)
  - webview_flutter_wkwebview (from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCrashlytics
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - FMDB
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleMaps
    - GoogleUtilities
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC
    - Reachability
    - ReachabilitySwift

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  awesome_notifications:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/awesome_notifications/ios"
  connectivity_plus:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios"
  device_info:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios"
  device_info_plus:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/ios"
  firebase_analytics:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios"
  firebase_core:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios"
  firebase_crashlytics:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios"
  firebase_messaging:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios"
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter
  flutter_app_badger:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_app_badger/ios"
  flutter_local_notifications:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios"
  flutter_statusbarcolor_ns:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns/ios"
  geocoding:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/geocoding/ios"
  geolocator_apple:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios"
  google_maps_flutter:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios"
  keyboard_visibility:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/keyboard_visibility/ios"
  package_info:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios"
  path_provider_ios:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios"
  share_plus:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios"
  shared_preferences:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios"
  sqflite:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios"
  url_launcher_ios:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios"
  webview_flutter_wkwebview:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  awesome_notifications: 04530aafec8dac4635244ed4b4072f4aea6cc938
  connectivity_plus: 413a8857dd5d9f1c399a39130850d02fe0feaf7e
  device_info: d7d233b645a32c40dfdc212de5cf646ca482f175
  device_info_plus: e5c5da33f982a436e103237c0c85f9031142abed
  Firebase: 7e8fe528c161b9271d365217a74c16aaf834578e
  firebase_analytics: 93a816ccc2ab01c9d74af68c61b2c08da7ea8f91
  firebase_core: b0b382f1497ab407aceb25e41e3036c8798c1609
  firebase_crashlytics: 4855a96241cfc4cb92a81bebedc29ea29488373a
  firebase_messaging: 34dd10d1aa6d8f40d03660eeacd0452d62eec7aa
  FirebaseAnalytics: 2fc3876e2eb347673ad2f35e249ae7b15d6c88f5
  FirebaseCore: b84a44ee7ba999e0f9f76d198a9c7f60a797b848
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: fd0c8490f34287229c1d6c103d3a55f81ec85712
  FirebaseCrashlytics: 079ef36f5c4b7161188928faec40fa276ebefd84
  FirebaseInstallations: 7d1d967a307c12f1aadd76844fc321cef699b1ce
  FirebaseMessaging: 5ebc42d281567658a2cb72b9ef3506e4a1a1a6e4
  Flutter: 50d75fe2f02b26cc09d224853bb45737f8b3214a
  flutter_app_badger: 65de4d6f0c34a891df49e6cfb8a1c0496426fa68
  flutter_local_notifications: 0c0b1ae97e741e1521e4c1629a459d04b9aec743
  flutter_statusbarcolor_ns: 68a360889d88d7915ae524e422aeab62e4063804
  FMDB: 2ce00b547f966261cd18927a3ddb07cb6f3db82a
  geocoding: 32cfcdb16d38d907caaba65e2e42ad10d38bee58
  geolocator_apple: cc556e6844d508c95df1e87e3ea6fa4e58c50401
  google_maps_flutter: c59fc576c0d0c7f4dc4bd63832c862d22d5a7c6d
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 71156240babd3cc6ced03e0d54816f01a880c730
  GoogleDataTransport: 629c20a4d363167143f30ea78320d5a7eb8bd940
  GoogleMaps: eb03e327edfd70b06de1e6e321653f73712df7ad
  GoogleUtilities: e0913149f6b0625b553d70dae12b49fc62914fd1
  keyboard_visibility: 96a24de806fe6823c3ad956c01ba2ec6d056616f
  nanopb: a0ba3315591a9ae0a16a309ee504766e90db0c96
  package_info: 873975fc26034f0b863a300ad47e7f1ac6c7ec62
  path_provider_ios: 14f3d2fd28c4fdb42f44e0f751d12861c43cee02
  PromisesObjC: 99b6f43f9e1044bd87a95a60beff28c2c44ddb72
  Reachability: 33e18b67625424e47b6cde6d202dce689ad7af96
  ReachabilitySwift: 985039c6f7b23a1da463388634119492ff86c825
  share_plus: 056a1e8ac890df3e33cb503afffaf1e9b4fbae68
  shared_preferences: af6bfa751691cdc24be3045c43ec037377ada40d
  sqflite: 6d358c025f5b867b29ed92fc697fd34924e11904
  url_launcher_ios: 839c58cdb4279282219f5e248c3321761ff3c4de
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: b7e70ef1ddded7e69c796c7390ee74180182971f


COCOAPODS: 1.11.2
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for FirebaseMessaging and adding the pod for both targets fixed it.
I found this solution in their github https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/7141

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end
```

Maybe you can adapt it for reachability.